# What can we say about the relationship between a weak entity and a strong entity it depends on?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I understand that a weak entity depends on a strong entity. But does it have its own primary key and is there a specific relation between strong and weak entity?

Also how do we represent the cardinality of the relation between the two entities using parentheses? (Example: weak entity, (1,1).)

Comment: can u pls elaborate little more?

Comment: 1. Does the weak entity has it's own primary key?

Comment: This is the first time I hear the term "weak entity" and looking it up on Wikipedia it shows that the whole thing is a bit blurry. An order position table needs the context of the order table, so it's a weak entity. But so does the order table need the user and the product as its context. Thinking it through: Every non-nullable foreign key makes its table a "weak entity". I doubt very much that this term is helpful in any way. But to answer the question: This has nothing to do with the table's primary key. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_entity

Answer (score 0):

Weak entities do have their own primary keys, which is a composite of another entity's primary key and at least one other column .  The "parent" entity may itself be a weak entity or a strong entity.

By including the "parent" entity's primary key in the dependent entity's, a binary relationship is automatically established between them, as well as with any other "ancestor" entities up to the most recent strong entity.  The cardinality of this relationship is one ("parent") entity to many (dependent) entities.

[image: Strong and weak entities in ER]

Understand that:

- The primary key of StrongEntity is `PrimaryKeyAttribute`.
- The primary key of WeakEntity1 is `PrimaryKeyAttribute, WeakKeyAttribute1`.
- The primary key of WeakEntity2 is `PrimaryKeyAttribute, WeakKeyAttribute1, WeakKeyAttribute2`.

In textual form, the weak entity's key is sufficient representation of the relationship between it and its "parent" entity, since the functional dependency of the "parent" key on the "child" key follows trivially, e.g. `(PrimaryKeyAttribute, WeakKeyAttribute1) -> PrimaryKeyAttribute`.  Cardinality can be indicated as 1:M or described as one-to-many (more specifically, one-to-one-or-more or one-to-zero-or-more).